# Skip a full directory with yaml in Google Cloud

Tags: yaml

I try to skip a directory with yaml in Google Cloud, my app.yaml is:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

skip_files:
- assets/

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

But, it doesn't work, Do you know which is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax and worked on my project with the same php version, api version and thread safety.

Did you deploy and wait a few minutes for it to take effect? It usually takes 3 minutes after the deploy completion for the changes to be in effect.

You can check which versions of your application are running with `gcloud app versions list`.

Also, if you're using local development (dev_appserver.py), then the skip_files directive will be ignored and they will be served normally.